# Cerrar Sesion (App.blade)

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando con laravel, tengo el siguiente codigo para el archivo de layout app.blade: el problema es que cuando inicio una sesion no me aparece el boton para cerrar la sesion

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../assets/img/apple-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../assets/img/favicon.png">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title>
    @yield ('title', 'App Shop')
  </title>
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />
  <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Material+Icons" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link href="{{ asset('css/material-kit.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
  <link href="{{ asset('demo/demo.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="@yield('body-class')">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-color-on-scroll fixed-top navbar-expand-lg" color-on-scroll="100" id="sectionsNav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-translate">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url ('/') }}">
          APP SHOP </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                        @guest
                            <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('login') }}">Iniciar Sesion</a></li>
                            <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('register') }}">Registrarse</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" 
                                aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick= "event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Desconectarse
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" 
                                        style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest

        <!--  <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="" data-placement="bottom" href="https://twitter.com/CreativeTim" target="_blank" data-original-title="Follow us on Twitter">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="" data-placement="bottom" href="https://www.facebook.com/CreativeTim" target="_blank" data-original-title="Like us on Facebook">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="" data-placement="bottom" href="https://www.instagram.com/CreativeTimOfficial" target="_blank" data-original-title="Follow us on Instagram">
              <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="wrapper">
      @yield('content')
  </div>


</body>

<!--   Core JS Files   -->
  <script src="{{ asset('js/core/jquery.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/core/popper.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/core/bootstrap-material-design.min.jss') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
  <!--  Plugin for the Datepicker, full documentation here: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker -->
  <script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--  Plugin for the Sliders, full documentation here: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ -->
  <script src="{{ asset('js/plugins/nouislider.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>
  <!-- Control Center for Material Kit: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
  <script src="{{ asset('js/material-kit.js?v=2.0.5') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿qué aparece entonces, el botón de iniciar sesión?

Comment: si pero al momento de iniciar la sesion despues no me aparece el boton de cerrar sesion, o desconectarse como puse en este caso

Comment: Hay una condición, ¿cuál de las dos condiciones es verdadera y su código aparece? Debe ser una de las dos.

Comment: Que tal si lo haces como indica la documentacion? "@auth"
    // The user is authenticated...
"@endauth"

"@guest"
    // The user is not authenticated...
"@endguest"...(sin las comillas dobles)

Comment: como? no entendi

Comment: Que pruebes utilizando las directivas guest para cuando no esté logueado y auth para cuando si. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade

Comment: osea el codigo me quedaria como el de la respuesta de abajo

Answer (score 0):

pon esto:
`<a href="{{ url('/logout') }}">logout</a>`

y en las rutas crea esta:

`Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');`

con eso deberia funcionar

Comment: Esto ha sido explicado en varias ocasiones por el creador de Laravel, y es considerado una mala práctica y no se recomienda hacerlo por cuestiones de seguridad, y no, ese no es el botón, ese es un formulario que permite enviar el POST.

Comment: Para la persona que votó positivo, le explico que esto es una pésima práctica y es considerado incorrecto dentro de la comunidad Laravel.

Comment: si la ruta es para poner el archivo web.php de la carpeta routes, te aviso que en la carpeta auth no tengo ningun LoginController@logout